# Hybris Cluster with a SOLR standalone installation

Tags: solr, cluster-computing, sap-commerce-cloud

before I describe my Problem, I want to describe my architecture and what I planned.

I've installed 6 Hybris Servers on 6 virtual machines called hybris01-hybris06.
They all are clustered and can see each other.
I followed these instructions:

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/SolrFacetSearch+-+Installation+Guide and made the following Setup:

I went to `hybris/bin/ext-commerce/solrfacetsearch/resources/solr/server/` and configured solr.xml and conf/solrconfig.xml.
Especially into the last one I added These lines:

```
  <solrconfig>
        <mode>standalone</mode>
    </solrconfig>

    <clusterconfig>
        <aliveCheckInterval>5000</aliveCheckInterval>
        <connectionTimeout>5000</connectionTimeout>
        <readTimeout>5000</readTimeout>
        <endpointURLs>
            <endpointURL master="true">hybris05:8983/solr</endpointURL>
            <endpointURL>hybris06:8983/solr</endpointURL>
        </endpointURLs>
    </clusterconfig>
```

and I also wrote this into the local.properties:

```
    solr.server.env=prod
    solr.server.mode=standalone
    solr.server.endpointURL=hybris05:8983/solr // and 06 on the other Server
```

But what I see is "using system property solr.solr.home: /opt/hybris/config/solr/embedded"

Now I am not sure if each Hybris instance is using embedded or standalone.

How can I find this out?

Greetings Fide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell Hybris to use your Standalone Solr cluster, to do so you need to go to the HMC :

> System -> Facet Search -> Facet Search Config -> Apparel Index
>   (example) -> Solr Configuration -> Edit the activated Solr Server
>   Configuration

You need to declare every members of your cluster here, you could write an impex query to insert this configuration. Don't forget that when you have a dedicated Solr master, the Indexer Mode could be Direct (faster) without any front-end index interruption.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is using the XML Configuration, which cannot be updated at runtime. Use the Item based config, available since 4.5 (or roundabout then is when Klaus added it).

As to your question as to whether it is running standalone or embedded, look at `http://localhost:9001/solrfacetsearch/`

Your data will be there if it is embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually the sold configuration can be done through HMC . steps to do
1. Login to HMC
2. Under system->facet search open ur solr facet object go to solr configuration tab and open the solr server configuration this is where u can see where u can see whether server is embedded or standalone

Thank you
Vinay

Comment: Hi Vinay, thanks for your answer,

but I was not able to follow your instruction.

What do you mean with my solr facet object?

Comment: Maybe I found it out now and it Looks like they are all embedded, but I cannot Change them because it's gray.
Any way to Change it in the hmc?

Comment: No you can't as it is only selected at the time of creation. You create a new one and use that.